# Splitting a column based on a condition of other columns

Tags: sql, columnsorting

I am trying to form a table to calculate user retention in sql. What I did so far was this:

```
SELECT date AS 'DAY', COUNT(userid) AS 'TOTAL LOGINS'
FROM dbo.login
GROUP BY date
```

In return I get this table:

[image]

However, some users in the total logins column have ios and some have androids. I want to add two extra columns to my table to show ios logins and android logins (sum of this two columns will be equal to total logins column for each row).

My original table (dbo.login) has a column named platform that displays every users platform. But I could not write a query to show the count of ios users or androis users in particular. Can you help me?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (MS SQL Server?)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT DATE AS 'DAY',COUNT(USERID) AS 'TOTAL LOGINS',
SUM(CASE WHEN [PLATFORM] = 'ANDROIDS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ANDROIDS,
SUM(CASE WHEN [PLATFORM] = 'ISO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ISO
FROM 
DBO.LOGIN GROUP BY DATE
```

Comment: please select right for other reference and give vote. @fsev